# pandas.DataFrame.replace with wildcards

Tags: python, regex, pandas, replace, dataframe

Does the [`pandas.DataFrame.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) regex replace support wildcards and "capture groups"?

E.g., to replace `([A-Z])(\w+)` with `\2\1`?

What kind of regular expression is supported? Does Perl's regex supported? E.g., OK to replace `([A-Z])(\w+)` with `\l\1\2` (`\l`: *Change the next character to lowercase*.)

**UPDATE:**

As Steve has pointed out, according to the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), it should work, but the following is not giving me what I expected:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.choice(['foo', 'bar'], 100),
                   'B': np.random.choice(['one', 'two', 'three'], 100),
                   'C': np.random.choice(['I1', 'I2', 'I3', 'I4'], 100),
                   'D': np.random.randint(-10,11,100),
                   'E': np.random.randn(100)})
df.replace("f(.)(.)","b\1\2", regex=True,inplace=True)
```

What's wrong?

Thx

Comment: You need to use raw strings in your regex patterns! The backslash is escaping the 1 and 2 characters in your string! This should work: `df.replace(r"f(.)(.)",r"b\1\2", regex=True, inplace=True)` Note the raw string for the first argument is overkill, but you should just get in the habbit of using them with regexprs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

> Regex substitution is performed under the hood with re.sub. The rules for substitution for re.sub are the same.

So, yes, any substitutions which can be performed with Python's `re.sub` (such as `\1`) can also be performed with `pandas.DataFrame.replace`.  See the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for more information.